# Developing Secure WebSocket Server using C#

Tags: c#, ssl, tls1.2

I am new to C# programming and have managed to develop non-secure C# websocket server. The server is working as expected with clients connecting to server from browser and c# client application using `ws://serverhostname:portnumber`.

Now, we have to move the working server to secure websocket server. I tried looking into many sites for help but still not very clear with the way to support secure websocket communication.

After  lot of research on internet, i found that we below on server to create the secure websocket server.

1. Create Signed Certificate on the server to use in `AuthenticateAsServer`.
2. Use `SslStream` class to create the secure stream.

But things which are still not clear to me are.

1. Do we need to use only `SslStream` object for sending and receiving data on secure websocket or we need use `SslStream` only for handshake and then use socket object (like my non secure server) to send and receive the data on the websocket.
2. Do we need to perform websocket handshake between client and server i.e. to upgrade from http to websocket
3. How do we encrypt or decrypt the data on `SslStream`.

Could you please help me with source code or links for the source code reference as i have tried all possible to get the information but could not find any as of now.

Comment: had you tried the example in this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you Tasos K,, for the response. Yes, i have checked this example but it does not say anything about websockets. The link talks more about sslstream and the way client and server communicates over sslatream, but my requodement is to provide secure wevsocket interface to client applications.

Comment: if your  goal is to provide a secure websocket you have to try SignalR

Comment: Thank you for the suggetion. Could you please help me with more information on why i cant get secure websocket implemented using ssl/tls. I have working non secure websocket server, so plan is to make changes to it so it should communicte with clients securely. Does sslstream doesnt work with websockets??

Comment: Also the server we are developing is not a web application, its a gateway application.

Comment: Yes even if it is a gateway SSL it's a host concern more than an SslStream

Comment: I have managed to create the server using sslstream and client application is able to open the connection to server but the challenge is with data sent by client to server. I see bytes recieved by server but unable to decode results into some special charecters. Can someone please help. Also, when i try to send some data to client, exception is raised on client side. Please help.